# Tracking native instructions in Intel PIN

Tags: c++, c, assembly, intel-pin

I am using the Intel PIN tool to do some analysis on the assembly instructions of a C program. I have a simple C program which prints "Hello World", which I have compiled and generated an executable. I have the assembly instruction trace generated from gdb like this-

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000400526 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400527 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
=> 0x000000000040052a <+4>:     mov    $0x4005c4,%edi
   0x000000000040052f <+9>:     mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400534 <+14>:    callq  0x400400 <printf@plt>
   0x0000000000400539 <+19>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040053e <+24>:    pop    %rbp
   0x000000000040053f <+25>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

I ran a pintool where I gave the executable as an input, and I am doing an instruction trace and printing the number of instructions. I wish to trace the instructions which are from my C program and probably get the machine opcodes and do some kind of analysis. I am using a C++ PIN tool to count the number of instructions-

```
#include "pin.H"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

UINT64 icount = 0;
using namespace std;

//====================================================================
// Analysis Routines
//====================================================================

void docount(THREADID tid) {
    icount++;
}

//====================================================================
// Instrumentation Routines
//====================================================================

VOID Instruction(INS ins, void *v) {
    INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)docount, IARG_THREAD_ID, IARG_END);
}

VOID Fini(INT32 code, VOID *v) {
    printf("count = %ld\n",(long)icount);
}

INT32 Usage() {
    PIN_ERROR("This Pintool failed\n"
              + KNOB_BASE::StringKnobSummary() + "\n");
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (PIN_Init(argc, argv)) return Usage();

    PIN_InitSymbols();
    PIN_AddInternalExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler,NULL);
    INS_AddInstrumentFunction(Instruction, 0);
    PIN_AddFiniFunction(Fini, 0);
    PIN_StartProgram();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run my hello world program with this tool, I get icount = 81563. I understand that PIN adds its own instructions for analysis, but I don't understand how it adds so many instructions, while I don't have more than 10 instructions in my C program. Also is there a way to identify the assembly instructions which are from my code and the ones generated by PIN. I seem to find no way to differentiate between instructions generated by PIN and the ones which are from my program. Please Help!

Comment: I am not familiar with PIN but presumably it's also counting the instructions in the C library.

Comment: Try making a static executable that just makes an `exit` system call directly.  (e.g. take out the loop from my [mov elimination microbenchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all/44193770#44193770)).

Comment: @PeterCordes Whatever  be the contents of my C program, icount always is above 80k. I don't know if there is a way to differentiate between the machine instructions and the ones generated by PIN.

Comment: The code for `printf` isn't generated by PIN, it's instructions that your program runs on its own.  So is the CRT start and exit code.  So try PIN on a program that just exits right away without the CRT and without calling any library functions.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I still get a similar number as before. I suspect it is due to some libraries of Pin

Answer (score 1):

You're not measuring what you think you're measuring. See my answer here for details:
[What instructions 'instCount' Pin tool counts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636662/what-instructions-instcount-pin-tool-counts)

Pin does **not** count its own instructions. The large count is the result of preparation before and after `main()` and the call to `printf()`.

Comment: I [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596570/tracking-native-instructions-in-intel-pin#comment80146865_46596570) the OP should try making a static executable that just makes a `sys_exit` system call from `_start`.  The OP says they got a "similar number of instructions", but your answer indicates they probably did it wrong.

Comment: I certainly suspect that this is the case. I haven't done it for a while but I remember that making such an executable is a little tricky.

Comment: Not if you do it all the time for microbenchmarking anyway :P  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all/44193770#44193770 (and take out the loop, leaving just `_start: xor edi,edi` / `mov eax, 231` / `syscall`.)  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649 for how to assemble + link NASM source into a static executable (no libc).